# Insertar datos en varias tablas relacionadas por el mismo campo

Tags: sql, mysqli

Vereís, tengo un problema a la hora de almacenar datos en la web que estoy creando. La base de datos que tengo consiste en una tabla que almacena unos datos y tiene un campo autoincremental como clave principal, esta tabla se relaciona con varias que tienen que introducir datos diferentes pero tienen el mismo id que la tabla principal, más o menos tengo una idea de como puedo hacerlo, pero esta idea falla en cuanto un mismo usuario quiere hacer un nuevo registro ya que no se como decirle que en las subtablas coja ese nuevo id. ¿Alguna idea de como puedo solucionar eso?

Comment: Parece que ocupas algo como `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) values (val1, val2); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @id; INSERT INTO other_table (..., t_id, ...) VALUES (..., @id, ...);` Lo tomé de [esta página](https://riptutorial.com/es/mysql/example/19942/insertar-con-auto-increment-plus-last-insert-id---), para que te des una vuelta por ahí a ver si te ayuda más que yo.

Comment: Gracías por la ayuda, la verdad que era algo así lo que buscaba, pero resulta que por algún motivo no me devuelve el id, aunque al final conseguí solucionarlo usando variables de sesión.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando variables de sesión, conseguí pasar el id necesario para identificar los datos y poder ejecutar el siguiente insert sin problemas.